# Do adapter classes use the methods of Event classes?

Tags: java, class, events, adapter

I'm kinda confused that adapter classes in java use the methods of any event class. Beginner level question.

Answer (score 0):

An adapter implements all of the abstract methods from the `Listener` interface it implements, you only have to override the ones you have to customize :

For instance, [KeyAdapter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyAdapter.html) implements all the methods from [KeyListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html) : `keyPressed`, `keyReleased` and `keyTyped`.

If you want to do something special with e.g `keytyped`, you would create a subclass of `KeyAdapter` and override only this method :

```
public class MyKeyAdapter extends KeyAdapter {

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke){

    char typedChar = ke.getKeyChar();   
    // do some custom things e.g depending on the typed character

    }

}
```

Adapters are useful because you don't have to implement all the methods of the listener interface, they already provide default NO-OP implementations of all methods.